# Подскажите скрипт или мануал на русском языке

Tags: jquery

Всем добрый день никак не могу найти нормального скрипта или мануала для организации следующей задачи.

Необходимо сделать вертикальное меню следующего типа:

```
Ссылка 1
  Ссылка 1
  Ссылка 2
    Ссылка 1
    Ссылка 2
      Ссылка 1
      Ссылка 2
    Ссылка 3
  Ссылка 3
  Ссылка 4
Ссылка 2
Ссылка 3
Ссылка 4
```

Вообщем до 4 уровней вложенности вся задача заключается в том что бы сделать акордион работающий по событию наведение мыши и что бы каждая ссылка была кликабельная и переходила на соответствующую страницу. Подскажите кто делал уже.

Answer (score 1):

тут в принципе мануал не обязателен. Структура меню делается вложенным списком. В элементе списка, который должен содержать подменю, на одном уровне располагаются ссылка и список. Примерно так:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="">Большой раздел</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Первый пункт подменю</a>
            <li><a href="">Второй пункт подменю</a>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Другой большой раздел</a></li>
</ul>
```

Изначально вложенные списки скрыты:

```
ul ul { display: none; }
```

При наведении на ссылку соседний список показывается:

```
$('a').mouseover(function(){$(this).siblings('ul').show()})
```

при уходе из списка, тот скрывается:

```
$('ul ul').mouseleave(function(){$(this).hide()})
```

Comment: Такой вариант я и сам знаю как сделать проблема в этом варианте в том если не сделать какой-либо стопор при быстром переходе по разделам получится плавающая непонятная ерунда а не меню.(Имеется в виду если провести мышкой по всем разделам вверх вниз несколько раз)

Comment: ну уж такова идея, что поделать.
А вообще, можно и задержку ставить:

    var hTimeout
    $('a').mouseover(function(){hTimeout=setTimeout(function(){$(this).siblings('ul').show()},100})

и

$('ul ul').mouseleave(function(){clearTimeout(hTimeout);$(this).hide()})

Comment: Оставлю как вариант про запас

Comment: опять .finish() забыли